# Calculate the maximum voltage can be applied across multiple capacitor?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, capacitance

[image: circuit]

How to calculate the maximum voltage can be applied to this circuit before the capacitors broken.

Each capacitors Voltage Rating is 60 V.

My solutions:
The right wire maximum is 60 + 60 + 60 = 180 V.
The left wire maximum is (60) + 60 = 120 V.

So the maximum overall is 120 V.
Is this correct?

Comment: For recommendations of alternative sites which might be suitable see [my question was closed on phys se - can you recommend me another internet site?](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/) You might like to try http://physics.qandaexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid it is note quite as easy as the method the you have used because if the voltage across the two parallel capacitors is $V$ the voltage across the capacitor in series with them is not $V$.
The reason for this is that the total charge on the parallel combination of capacitors must be the same as the charge on the capacitor in series with them.
So you need to decide how the voltage applied to the whole arrange the is split between the two capacitors in parallel and the capacitor in series with them.

Comment: Thanks. I got it. Is the answer **90**? The capacitor which will break first is the one on the left wire that connects series to parallel.

Comment: Yes, the voltage across C4 is always going to be twice that of the C2 and C3 parallel arrangement.